# RoR Response output type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I want my Rails rest application has json as default  output format , also I want remove html format. Any suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

In your controller,

```
respond_to do |format|
  #format.html # show.html.erb
  #format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
  format.json { render :json => @post }
end
```

or you can handle it as javascript

```
 respond_to do |format| format.js { render :json { :only => :name}.to_json end

 then you just access your action with ".js" in the end
```

Try like this

```
  format.any(:xml, :html, :json) { render :json => @post }
```

Comment: how to make default rendering in json without using respond_to block ?